# How to deal with indexes of multiple where query in firebase?

Tags: database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

In my flutter app. I have to fetch data from firebase using multiple filters.

I've done as below. It worked but the problem is that some filter is null so I need to skip it in the firebase query, therefore, even I have only 2 fields (name, age) I have to create 3 indexes for supporting my query. 1st index is for: name, 2nd index is for: age, 3rd index is for: name and age.

```
Future<List<Transac>> getTrans(TransFilter filter, Transac? lastTrans) async {
const limit = 10;
var result =
    _collection.orderBy(filter.orderBy, descending: true).limit(limit);

if (filter.directionId != null) {
  result = result.where(directionIdKey, isEqualTo: filter.directionId);
}

if (filter.flag != null) {
  result = result.where(Transac.flagKey, isEqualTo: filter.flag);
}

if (filter.officeId != null) {
  result = result.where(officeIdKey, isEqualTo: filter.officeId);
} 

if (lastTrans != null) {
  result = result.startAfter([lastTrans.createdAt.millisecondsSinceEpoch]);
}

final _result = await result.get().then(
    (value) => value.docs.map((e) => Transac.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());

return _result;
}
```

I have tried something as below because I think I just need to create all indexs at once, but it throws an error because I cannot use isNotEqualTo on the field that not use in the first orderby.

```
Future<List<Transac>> getTrans(TransFilter filter, Transac? lastTrans) async {
const limit = 10;
var result =
    _collection.orderBy(filter.orderBy, descending: true).limit(limit);

if (filter.directionId != null) {
  result = result.where(directionIdKey, isEqualTo: filter.directionId);
}else {
  result = result.where(directionIdKey, isNotEqualTo: '');
}

if (filter.officeId != null) {
  result = result.where(officeIdKey, isEqualTo: filter.officeId);
}else {
  result = result.where(officeIdKey, isNotEqualTo: '');
}


if (lastTrans != null) {
  result = result.startAfter([lastTrans.createdAt.millisecondsSinceEpoch]);
}

final _result = await result.get().then(
    (value) => value.docs.map((e) => Transac.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());

return _result;
}
```

Any solution or suggestion? Your help will be much appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 parameters that you want to filterBy `directionIdKey`, `Transac.flagKey`, `officeIdKey`. You want to orderBy: `filter.orderBy`.

I believe these parameters are holding the field names.

We need a field that will be present in all queries. We use your orderBy field.
So create 3 composite indexes.

1. filter.orderBy and directionIdKey ASC
2. filter.orderBy and Transac.flagKey ASC
3. filter.orderBy and officeIdKey ASC

This should handle your queries.

Comment: Thank you that's worked. Because I was misunderstanding how the index work. I thought I have to create all indexes of visible fields. Thank so much

Comment: You're welcome. So glad I could help.